# How can I programmatically return the location (row and column) of a keyword

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to use python to automate the analysis of hundreds of excel files.  Currently I can open, write, and save files but I need to insert calculations in cells that contain keywords.  I am using python 2.7, here is a snipet from my code where I am struggling:

```
def run_analysis():
    excel = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    excel.DisplayAlerts = False
    keyword = "Total Traffic"
    x = 0
    t = data_file_location_list

    while x < len(t):
        #for files in data_file_location_list:
        wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(t[x].root_dir + "\\" + t[x].file_name)
        ws = wb.Sheets('Bandwidth Over Time')

        keyword_range = #here is where I am stuck

        ws.Range(keyword_range).Value = 'write something'
        wb.SaveAs(Filename=str(t[x].root_dir + "\\" + t[x].file_name))
        wb.Close()
        excel.Quit()
        print x
        x += 1
```

Comment: Can you give us some sample data of how your Excel workbook would be set out? For example, where would you be setting the formulas and what values would you be looking for, are you writing over the cell value when you find a keyword, or are you writing to the adjacent cell?

Comment: @girlvsdata I am just going to write a formula over the keyword.  Once I can figure out how to return the range of the keyword the rest is cake!

Comment: which python package are you using to work with Excel?

Comment: @girlvsdata win32com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone was following this action, I figured it out and thought I would share the answer.  The FindCell function was what I came up with, although there is probably a much more elegant way to do this.

```
def run_analysis():
    excel = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    excel.DisplayAlerts = False
    x = 0
    t = data_file_location_list

    while x < len(t):
        # MATCHES ROW AND COL INPUT FOR CELL ADDRESS OUTPUT
        def FindCell(descriptor, banner):
            return(ws.Cells(excel.WorksheetFunction.Match(descriptor, ws.Range("B:B"), 0), 
                               excel.WorksheetFunction.Match(banner, ws.Range("A:A"), 0)).Address)

        try:
            print 'opening: ' + t[x].root_dir + "\\" + t[x].file_name

            wb                                 = excel.Workbooks.Open(t[x].root_dir + "\\" + t[x].file_name)
            ws                                 = wb.Sheets('Bandwidth Over Time')  

            #find the cell below the cell containing "Total Traffic"
            total_traffic_calc_range           = FindCell("Traffic", 'Bandwidth Over Time')
            total_traffic_calc_range_delimiter = int(total_traffic_calc_range.strip('$A$'))
            total_traffic_equation_cell        = "C" + str(total_traffic_calc_range_delimiter)

            #add the equations for calculation
            ws.Range(total_traffic_equation_cell).Value = '=Sum(' + 'B' + str(
                    total_traffic_calc_range_delimiter + 1) + ':B' + str(
                            total_throughput_calc_range_delimiter - 2) + ')'

            wb.SaveAs(Filename = str(t[x].root_dir + "\\" + t[x].file_name))

        except Exception as e:
            print e

        finally:
            wb.Close()
            excel.Quit()
            print x
            x += 1
```